# Selecting a date on JCalendar to create a dialog box

Tags: windowbuilder, jcalendar

I am working on a project that uses an interactive calendar. I intended for the user to click a date on the JCalendar, and if an event took place on that day then a pop-up would display, telling the user what event took place. If there was no event on that day, a pop-up would display telling the user that there was no event that day. How would I register this interaction with the JCalendar, and turn this interaction into a dialog box on the screen?

Answer (score 1):

Add a `PropertyChangeListener` to your `JCalendar` for `"calendar"`. Check the resulting `Date` against your event and bring up a `JOptionPane` to show the result.

```
JCalendar jc = new JCalendar(c);
jc.addPropertyChangeListener("calendar", new PropertyChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getPropertyName() + ": "
            + ((GregorianCalendar)e.getNewValue()).getTime());
    }
});
```